# how to find middle point of a sorted array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have an arry lets say

A=[2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

i want to get middle point

like B=[5]

how to do it?

Comment: FYI, this is called the median.

Comment: By what definition is that the middle point?

Answer (score 12):

Try to use `end` to automatically obtain the index of the last entry, and use `ceil` to round up the half length when the length is not even

```
B=A(ceil(end/2))
```

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB's built-in [median](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/median.html) function will work. If you have an array with an odd number of elements it pulls the middle point. Otherwise if you have an even number of points, it averages the two points in the middle.